# Combining weeks 52 and 0 with Python Datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

I have a Pandas DataFrame with daily data that I'm trying to group by week number to sum some columns, and I notice that when years do not begin on Sunday, the data for the week spanning the end of one year and the beginning of the next do not cleanly sum, instead being broken into two groups. My code to create a week number column is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
  {'Date': 2020-03-01, 'population': 100, 'admission': 10, 'release': 10, 'feature_id': 'abc'},
  {'Date': 2020-03-02, 'population': 100, 'admission': 10, 'release': 10, 'feature_id': 'abc'},
  ...
])


df['week_num'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%U')
by_week = df.groupby(["week_num", "feature_id"])[["population", "admission", "release"]].sum().reset_index()
```

When I look at my grouped data, I see the following:

```
...,
{
  'week_num': '2020-52',
  'start_of_week': '2020-12-27T00:00:00.000Z',
  'end_of_week': '2021-01-02T00:00:00.000Z',
  'population': 1000,
  'admission': 100,
  'release': 150
},
{
  'week_num': '2021-00',
  'start_of_week': '2020-12-27T00:00:00.000Z',
  'end_of_week': '2021-01-02T00:00:00.000Z',
  'population': 200,
  'admission': 120,
  'release': 90
},
...
```

In reality, the summed values for the week from 2020-12-27 to 2021-01-02 should be a single group, `population=1000+200=1200, admission=100+120=220, release=150+90=240`.

Is there a clean way to create a `week_num` column that takes into account this end-of-year hiccup and sums a single week?

**Edit**

It appears the issue may derive from the application of a `Week` class to extract start and end of week, as follows:

```
class Week:
    def __init__(self, year, week_num):
        week_start = str(year) + " " + str(week_num) + " 0"
        week_end = str(year) + " " + str(week_num) + " 6"
        self.first_date = dt.datetime.strptime(week_start, '%Y %U %w')
        self.last_date = dt.datetime.strptime(week_end, '%Y %U %w')

...

by_week["start_of_week"] = by_week["iso_week_num"].apply(lambda w: Week(*w.split("-")).first_date)
```

**Final from answer**

```
df["week_num"] = df["Date"].dt.strftime("%G-%V")
by_week = df.groupby(["week_num", "feature_id"])[["population", "admission", "release"]].sum().reset_index()
by_week["start_of_week"] = by_week["week_num"].apply(lambda d: datetime.strptime(d+"1", "%G-%V%u"))
by_week["end_of_week"] = by_week["week_num"].apply(lambda d: datetime.strptime(d+"7", "%G-%V%u"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%U breaks the week around new year as per documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Replace %U with %V and %Y with %G for the original code to work as expected (from python 3.6 onward).

For python < 3.6 use isocalendar():

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'Date': pd.Timestamp('2020-12-20') + pd.Timedelta(n, 'day'), 'population': 100, 'admission': 10, 'release': 10,
     'feature_id': 'abc'}
    for n in range(21)
])

df = pd.concat([df, (df['Date'] + pd.Timedelta(1, 'day')).dt.isocalendar()], axis=1)
df['start_of_week'] = df.apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.fromisocalendar(x.year, x.week, 1), axis=1)
df['end_of_week'] = df.apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.fromisocalendar(x.year, x.week, 7), axis=1)
df["iso_week_num"] = (df['Date'] + pd.Timedelta(1, 'day')).apply(lambda t: f'{t.isocalendar().year}-{t.isocalendar().week}')

by_iso_week = df.groupby(["year", "week", "feature_id"])[["population", "admission", "release"]].sum().reset_index()

df["start_of_week2"] = df["iso_week_num"].apply(lambda w: Week(*w.split("-")).first_date)
```

Comment: Hi @bzu, I will post more complete source data, but when I run this way, I get a week 53 for 2020 that runs from 2021-01-03 to 2021-01-09, so just mirrors the issue...

Comment: @OJT It works for me, 27th to 2nd is the same week with number 53 (on pandas 1.3.5). Which day do you want the week to start? Sunday?

Comment: I edited to include some additional code that generates first and last dates of week... I think this may be part of the issue, since it creates overlapping start and end dates even though the week numbers are different.

Comment: @OJT I've added the start and end of week dates, you need to avoid %U as it will break the weak around new year in 2: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

You could possibly also try your solution by replacing %U with %V.

Comment: Using %V and %G did the trick, thank you!